# PHP odbc connection to sqlserver on windows server 2008 R2 64bit

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I have an application that connects to Ms SQL Server 2008 using ODBC and it was running perfect on windows 7 32bit.

Howerver, when I move the same to Windows Server 2008 R2, it throws the following error :

```
Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application, SQL state IM014 in SQLConnect in C:\wamp\www\usd\connect_odbc.php on line 2
```

Please help

Comment: Windows 2008 R2 is 64 bit only. Is it running on IIS?

Comment: The application is running on WAMP 2.4 32bit. Apache Version :2.4.4  PHP Version :5.4.16  MySQL Version :5.6.12

Comment: did you create the odbc connection in the 32 bit portion of the odbc app? c:\windows\syswow64\odbcad32.exe

Comment: no, odbc connection is created in C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your odbc connection in the 32 bit odbc application located in the SYSWOW64 directory. c:\windows\syswow64\odbcad32.exe